# UrbanAirship Notification Implementaion in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

i m trying to build test app to integrate urbanairship notification. I am following `https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android/#getting-started` and `https://michiganlabs.com/2014/01/31/push-notification-urban-airship/` and accordingly register my new project in FCM too. I have also register my package with API Key and sender Id in urbanairship.

Below is code for Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jss.urabn">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Autopilot calls takeOff without the need to override the Application -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.urbanairship.autopilot"
            android:value="com.urbanairship.Autopilot"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
```

Code for Mainactivity

```
package jss.urabn;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions;
import com.urbanairship.UAirship;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);
                options.developmentAppKey = 'Your development app key';
                options.productionAppKey = 'Your production app key';
                options.inProduction = false;




    }
}
```

I m not getting error on loaddefaultoptions method (Can not resolve method).

Can anybody guide.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Autopilot, it will pull the options directly from airshipconfig.properties file. If you are trying to manually customize the options, you have to do so in a custom Autopilot class or by overriding the main application. Not in the MainActivity that you have above.

In your manifest:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.urbanairship.autopilot"
        android:value="cjss.urabn.SampleAutopilot"/>
```

Then define an AutoPilot class:

```
package jss.urabn;

public class SampleAutopilot extends Autopilot {

    @Override
    public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
         airship.getPushManager().setUserNotificationsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public AirshipConfigOptions createAirshipConfigOptions(@NonNull Context context) {
        AirshipConfigOptions options = new AirshipConfigOptions.Builder()
                .applyDefaultProperties(context)
                .setInProduction(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setDevelopmentAppKey("Your Development App Key")
                .setDevelopmentAppSecret("Your Development App Secret")
                .setProductionAppKey("Your Production App Key")
                .setProductionAppSecret("Your Production App Secret")
                .setNotificationAccentColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_accent))
                .setNotificationIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .build();

        return options;
    }
}
```

The AirshipConfig class has changed to a immutable. You know how to define it using the builder. The method 'loadDefaultOptions' maps to the builders 'applyDefaultProperties'.